# Kiviet corrected estimator for dynamic panels

Tags: dynamic, panel

I am interested in simulating a dynamic panel model using the kiviet bias corrected estimator?

Yit=ro*yit[-1]+b1*xit+eit
Any available code for this estimator?

I am trying to avoid gmm or iv estimators as both N and T are  small